# Best Practice: Java attributes might be null

Tags: java, constructor, getter

So I have a constructor with 5 different variables, where three of which might be null. It accepts user input and the user does not have to enter anything for three of the five attributes.
Therefore, if the user did not enter anything, the object is created using null for all missing values.

```
obj = new Object(String, null, null, null, String);
```

Now I am wondering what would be best practice to cope with this.
I can think of three different scenarios:

- Deal with it only in the class using the constructor, i.e. always query whether the value is null (e.g. `if(getSomeAttribute == null) { //do something }`
- Deal with it within the object class, i.e. always return some default value for each missing attribute instead of null
- Deal with it within the object lcass, i.e. have helper-methods like `isAttributeSet()`, returning a boolean value indicating whether the attributes are set, that is: not null.

Although I have problems with the last two, as I think I might run into problems with default values, as sometimes it might hard to know if it is a default value; if I'd always check I could just as well check for null instead of inserting a default value first;
Same with the last one, if I have to check the helper-method, I could just as well check for null directly.

What my problem is with this situation, is that sometimes I might not be the one using the getter and setter methods; how should the one using it know there might be null attributes and which that are.
I know, I should document that within my object class, but still I am wondering if there is a "best practice" way to cope with this.
I believe it should be unusual to always check the documentary (or if there is none, the whole class) for something as simple as this.
Maybe I should not even start with null values within my constructor in the first place? But I think I would run into the same kinds of problems, anyway, so that would not really solve my problem

Comment: If these variables are optional, then use ... [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: I agree with Tom, you should avoid `null` in the first place. If `Optional` is - uh - not an option, consider factories / builders or factory methods. Consider the programming coming after you, finding a call such as `obj = new Object(String, null, null, null, String);`. Now you have to think about each null in the call what kind of parameter is actually expected; `null` is not much of a hint.

Answer (score 6):

Read Bloch, Effective Java, 2nd ed. Item 2: "Consider a builder when faced with many constructor parameters."

Excellent advice in an excellent book.

Comment: Here is [the item in Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA5&pg=PA11#v=onepage&q&f=false) and here is [the source code](https://github.com/marhan/effective-java-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/org/effectivejava/examples/chapter02/item02) for that item.

Comment: Thanks. It does not help me with the confusion of default values, does it? As far as I understand, the builder sets all attributes; all optional attributes are set to default values in advance. Therefore, my object is initialized with these values as well. I could just use default values myself then, as I do not have that many optional values, just three.

Answer (score 0):

Using a builder pattern would help with the constructor, however the main problem is to do with the design of the class - you want to be sure when you call a get/set method that it isn't one of the null/optional members.

You could use polymorphism to have two objects each with an interface that only exposes the getters and setters supported by the concrete implementation. This makes it impossible to call the wrong getters/setters and it is obvious what the intention is.